# rabbitsvn deleted **all** my folders?

Tags: 12.04, data-loss, rabbitvcs, undelete

I was working with rabbitsvn and trying to export a file from an older revision, when suddenly all programs in the background just shut down. I go to my "Home"-folder to find out that **all** (!!) my folders and data except a single one has been deleted.

Not only that, many of my programs have also been deleted (like Dropbox) + Firefox was reset, so I lost all my bookmarks and active logins. My Unity-launcher was also reset.

How on earth is this possible? What should I do to get my stuff back?!? I'm really close to jumping out the window!!!!!!

They are not present in the trash and not hidden.

Comment: I am not sure how this is possible but can you check if they are at least present in the trash, or may be hidden(press ctrl + h to unhide), or moved to some other location?

Comment: Unfortunately, your best bet next  is to use a data recovery software before you try to add/remove/modify data on your system now: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Answer (score 0):

You can use Testdisk to recover you lost data. Go to [Here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) for more details.